# Flask - templates without external files

Tags: python, templates, flask

Is it possible to use templates in Flask like in Bottle, without any external files? Just a template in a simple string variable. How would that work?

Comment: simple Flask example would be appreciate:)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`flask.render_template_string()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.render_template_string) to render a template stored in a string.

```
from flask import render_template_string

return render_template_string(
    '<body>{{ greeting }}</body>',
    greeting='Hello, World!')
```